# Is there precedent for a suspension of such a large number of MPs simultaneously?

Tags: parliament, india, history

India's parliament recently suspended over 140 opposition MPs for the remainder of the current session for causing ruckus.

To quote [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-67724698) for details:

> The [opposition] alliance has 142 MPs in the 543-member Lok Sabha - the lower house of parliament - of which 95 have now been suspended. It has 101 MPs in the 250-member upper house or Rajya Sabha (a few seats are vacant) - of these, 46 have been suspended.

Has such a thing happened before in India or other democracies at this scale? Over half of the opposition has been removed from the Parliament.

Comment: Well, I am reminded of how Israel put a bunch of Palestinian MPs in prison after 2006, but not the same situation... that suspension is kind of crazy. Is there going to be some uprising? Martial law? Crisis at the supreme court?

Comment: @einpoklum Yeah the palestinian one isn't comparable. Well the MPs were suspended for unruly behavior which they were indeed responsible for, the suspension is only for the current session which is almost done anyway, and there is an election in 6 months. So nothing is going to happen. Supreme Court doesn't intervene in parliamentary proceedings generally.

Answer (score -3):

6 december 1992: uttar pradesh govt was dismissed

15 december 1992: 3 state(HP, RJ, MP) governments were dismissed after the destruction of structure on RJB in uttar pradesh.

all 4 states had BJP govt and central was congress.

Comment: You should include more information about the number of affected MPs by these events, since the question explicitly mentions the large number (in the dozens) of affected MPs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and welcome to politics stack exchange. If you want information on the rules of our site you can find it at the [tour], [help], or [meta].

Comment: the data is available in public domain and dismissing government is much higher assault than suspending the MP's at the end of the term. hope the facts are accepted on site.

Comment: precise answer to the question would be 63 MP's were suspended in 1989